# Assistance with Python 'sort(key=None)'

Tags: python, sorting

I'm having a hard time understanding why my function is not returning the reversed version of my list. I've spent a long time trying to understand why and i hit a wall: ---it only returns my list in ascending order.

```
letters = 'abcdefghijk'
numbers = '123456'
dict1 = {}

def reverseOrder(listing):
    lst2 = []
    lst2.append(listing)
    lst2.sort(reverse=True)
    return lst2

for l, n in zip(letters, numbers):
    dict1.update({l:n})
    lst1 = list(dict1) + list(dict1.values())

lst1.sort(key=reverseOrder)
print(lst1)
```

Comment: Check here: [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted`), key should return a value that indicates sort order...

Comment: You're making the key a list itself, not a letter/number, and `lst2.sort(reverse=True)` will only ever be one value

Comment: Are you aware of the `list.reverse` method?

Comment: The `key` parameter only lets you sort in reverse order if you know enough about the items you are sorting (for example, `key=lambda x: -x` will sort numbers in reverse order, but not strings).

Comment: Not really clear what the expected output is, but `enumerate(letters)` will get you numbered tuples of letters. So, you really don't need the numbers string

Comment: Thanks all for your assistance. @ Patrick, yes i'm aware of the list.reverse method, the above was just my attempt to play around with the sort and zip functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `sort` function in an invalid way.

Here is the definition of `sort` function (from `builtins.py`):

```
def sort(self, key=None, reverse=False): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
    """ L.sort(key=None, reverse=False) -> None -- stable sort *IN PLACE* """
    pass
```

`key` argument has to be used if there is 'ambiguity' on how items have to be sorted e.g. items are tuples, dictionaries, etc.

Example:

```
lst = [(1, 2), (2, 1)]
lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[0]) # lst = [(1, 2), (2, 1)]
lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]) # lst = [(2, 1), (1, 2)]
```

Not quite sure what you want with this part though:

```
for l, n in zip(letters, numbers):
    dict1.update({l:n})
    lst1 = list(dict1) + list(dict1.values())
```

Seems like you want a list of all numbers and letters but you are doing it an odd way.

Edit: I have updated answer.

Comment: Python 3’s `list.sort()` does not support a `cmp` function. Also. OP is using a key function, so I’m not sure where your *“it has to return -1, 0 or 1”* is coming from exactly.

Comment: ahh, thanks ..the above code was basically my attempt to play around with both the sort function and zip function. much appreciated.

Comment: @poke yes, correct, I have updated the answer! Thanks!

Comment: You can use [`functools.cmp_to_key`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) to convert old-style `cmp` functions to new `key` functions.

Answer (score 1):

The `key` function passed to [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) has a very specific purpose:

> `key` specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element (for example, `key=str.lower`). The key corresponding to each item in the list is calculated once and then used for the entire sorting process. The default value of `None` means that list items are sorted directly without calculating a separate key value.

So the function is supposed to take in a single list element, and then return a key that determines its sorting compared to the other elements.

For example, if you wanted to sort a list by the length of their contents, you could do it like this:

```
def lengthOfItem (item):
    return len(item)

lst.sort(key=lengthOfItem)
```

Since the function only takes a *single* item, it makes it unsuitable for sorting behaviors where you actually need to compare two elements in order to make a relation. But those sortings are very inefficient, so you should avoid them.

In your case, it seems like you want to reverse your list. In that case you can just use [`list.reverse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types).